# RegCreateEx return 5 Access Denied on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, registry

I have one program that uses API RegCreateKeyEx and that works perfectly fine on WinXP and Vista.

Program is generally launched in elevated privileges .
When I try to use same program in Windows 7 , RegCreateKeyEx API is returning 5 (access denied).

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you create the key manually using regedit.exe? Perhaps it's a permission problem. Also, did you test on the same platform (32-bit or 64-bit) for the Windows versions you mentioned?

Comment: Not without more information. Where are you trying to create the key (HKLM, HKCU)? How are you opening the key? What does "generally launched" mean?

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs when you're trying to create a key in a portion of the registry where you don't have write access. On Windows 7, this is basically everywhere.

To increase compatibility of 32 bit applications between XP/7 it's suggested you create the key in the 32 bit view of the registry. Modify your call to include the mask `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` so it uses the 32 bit view:

```
result = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Foo"),
    NULL, NULL, NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, NULL, &hkey, &disposition);
```

Then create the key first in the registry manually under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Foo`. Edit the permissions and give yourself (or everyone) Full Control.

You should now be able to access the key from a 32 bit application.

Comment: *On Windows 7, this is basically everywhere*. Not true. HKCU is an obvious exception. And note that UAC was introduced in Vista so nothing important to this topic changed from Vista to 7. It's rare to need the registry view flags since redirection will usually deal with it for you. If the code is run from a 32 bit process, the redirector takes care of things. Finally, suggesting that the solution involves  manually creating the key and assigning rights is not very helpful for a site for programmers. The real issue here is a hopelessly imprecise question that should not be answered.